# what's the challenge in big data analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, data-mining, large-data

Could you guys give me a review on the challenges and common techniques in dealing with big data problem?

For example, what I know is that in when sample size is limited and dimension is high, the estimation of covariance would be an issue, what we did is to suppressing the big eigenvalues and increasing the small eigenvalues.

Comment: most of the articles/discussions that i see about big data have less to do with the analysis, and more to do with the issues of how to properly and safely store petabytes worth of data.  Banko and Brill published an (at the time controversial) article in 2001 that claimed that the actual algorithem used was of little concern, and that they all eventuall got to generally the same error rate.  What mattered was the amount of data used. data.http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/P/P01/P01-1005.pdf

Comment: Although you mentioned "sample size" I still wonder if the word "big" pertains to "data" or to "(data) analysis/problem"

Comment: I agree with BackGammon Cube. The challenge is dealing with that information from a storage/access point of view, rather than processing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is quite vague. It all depends on how you define *big data*. Since you added [machine-learning](/questions/tagged/machine-learning), I will talk a bit about that.

In terms of machine learning, large-scale learning routinely refers to tasks where your data sets won't fit in RAM anymore (hundreds of gigabytes). The challenge is simple: get *anything* done (preferably efficiently).

Some like to say that the main computational constraint in large-scale learning is **time**. Many nonlinear techniques become unfeasible when the number of instances/dimensions becomes large. Kernel methods are particularly susceptible to time inflation when the number of training instances gets huge (millions or more).

Often the only solution is to resort to subsampling or linear techniques and accept the performance penalty as a necessary evil.